# sql query works in phpmyadmin but not with mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am stuck with this.

Here is the code:

This is how I call the function,

`$res = DataManager::agregarPropiedad($_POST);`

here is the function that generate the query and send it,

```
public static function agregarPropiedad($datos){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO propiedades (id_propiedad, nombre, tipopropiedad, descripcion, dormitorios, baños, direccion, localidad, provincia, fecha_alta, sup_cubierta, sup_total)
  VALUES (null, '" . $datos['nombre'] . "', '" . $datos['tipo'] . "', '" . $datos['descripcion'] . "', '" . $datos['dormitorios'] . "', '" . $datos['baños'] . "', '" . $datos['direccion'] . "', '" . $datos['localidad'] . "', '" . $datos['provincia'] . "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '" . $datos['supcubierta'] . "', '" . $datos['suptotal'] . "')";
  //$sql = "insert into prueba values(null,'".$datos['nombre']."')";
  echo $sql; 
  return DataManager::consulta($sql);
```

}

When I copy the `echo`$sql and paste in phpMyAdmin works fine, but when I try to send my function is not inserting anything, but I have no errors. `mysql_erros()` its empty too.

U can see that, there is a commented `$sql`. I use that just for test with another table which is much simpler and query the function "consulta" which works fine too.

This is maybe the 40 function that insert things in mysql database, but the first with which I have problems, and I don't know why =(

helppppp...

Comment: Can you post what error it is giving?

Comment: Is the 'display_errors' parameter in your php.ini set to 'On'?

Comment: there are no errors. ; 
display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

Comment: Try inserting `echo mysql_error();` before `echo $sql` and post the result here.

Comment: ey Phius. i add but nothing shows up.

Comment: i solve the problem. my table have a field name baños whit ñ. seems that echo give the right character, but when i pass via mysql_query something mess up whit that char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From personal experience, MySQL queries that work when dumped / copied / pasted into PhPMyAdmin that  **don't** work in code are caused by:

- autoincrement / unique field issues
- unexpected characters in unprocessed form data
- duplicate POST values ( like an array )
- mismatched field count
- encoding / character set issues

It may well be that if you address the second issue the problem might fix itself. In any case at a minimum you should process you POST(ed) data with strip_tags and add_slashes, but for MySQL mysql_real_escape_string() is strongly recommended.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
http://www.adminsehow.com/2010/03/prevent-mysql-injection-in-php

Comment: tks for the answer, i will reserch in that direction. i try using what Johndave Decano said (real_escape_string), but its not working

Comment: i solve the problem. my table have a field name baños whit ñ. seems that echo give the right character, but when i pass via mysql_query something mess up whit that char.

Comment: Good news! Don't forget to protect against SQL injection attacks ( as mentioned in the link above ) to avoid any nasty surprises. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your quotes inside the VALUES() and its vulnerable.

```
<?php 
public static function agregarPropiedad($datos)
{
    $tipo = mysql_real_escape_string($datos['tipo']);
    $nomber = mysql_real_escape_string($datos['nombre']);
    $dormitorios = mysql_real_escape_string($datos['descripcion']);
    $baños = mysql_real_escape_string($datos['baños']);
    $direccion = mysql_real_escape_string($datos['direccion']);
    $localidad = mysql_real_escape_string($datos['localidad']);
    $provincia = mysql_real_escape_string($datos['provincia']);
    $supcubierta = mysql_real_escape_string($datos['supcubierta']);
    $suptotal = mysql_real_escape_string($datos['suptotal']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO propiedades (id_propiedad, nombre, tipopropiedad, descripcion, dormitorios, baños, direccion, localidad, provincia, fecha_alta, sup_cubierta, sup_total)";
    $sql .= "VALUES (null,'$tipo','$nomber ','$dormitorios ','$baños ','$direccion ','$localidad','$provincia ',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$supcubierta','$suptotal')";
    if(mysql_query($sql))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }else{ return FALSE; }
}
?>
```

Comment: tks for the response, i try it but its the same... both ways generates the sql query just fine because when i paste in phpmyadmin insert the row. but i am not having any answer when i try in php. 

also the same web have working others inserts like this, and all work whitout problems =(

Comment: i tryied xD its the same, i really have no clue whats going on here. my func its almost a copy of other functions that are working.

Comment: there is no error. NOTHING! thats why i cant find what its going on.

Comment: I just changed my code. If it didnt work check the column names inside the INTO propiedades (